# Checking equivalence of combinatorial terms.

Tags: solution-verification, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

Due to some context, I have reason to believe that S(K(SII)) and SSI are actually equivalent CL terms. This is my attempt at a proof (assuming a and b to be arbitrary CL terms):

$$\text{S(K(SII))ab = SII(ab) = ab(ab)}\\
\text{SSIab = Saab = ab(ab)}$$

Since both simplify to the same form, can we say that S(K(SII)) and SSI are equivalent terms?

[This problem arose when I was looking to describe the Y-combinator using only S, K and I. The [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#:%7E:text=the%20y%20combinator%20can%20be%20expressed%20in%20the%20ski%2Dcalculus%20as) starts with S(K(SII)), while mine starts with SSI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems to work, but I'm not sure. However you can use lambda calculus to show a beta equivalence. That works guaranteed:
$$I:=\lambda x.x, \quad K:=\lambda x. \lambda y. x, \quad S := \lambda x. \lambda y. \lambda z. xz(yz)$$
The first term reduces to:
$$ SII = \lambda z. (\lambda x.x) z ((\lambda x.x)z) \rightarrow_\beta \lambda z.zz  \\ S(K(SII)) = \lambda y . \lambda z. ( \lambda y . \lambda z . zz) z (yz) \rightarrow_\beta \lambda y . \lambda z. yz(yz)$$
And the second to (Keep in mind to rename conflicting variables!):
$$ SS = \lambda y . \lambda z. ( \lambda x. \lambda y . \lambda z. xz(yz))z(yz) \rightarrow_\beta \lambda y . \lambda z. (\lambda z'. z z' (yz z'))\\
SSI = \lambda z . \lambda  z' . z z' (z z') =_\alpha \lambda y . \lambda z. yz(yz)$$
Therefore $SSI$ and $S(K(SII))$ are $\beta$-equivalent.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for having done all that hard work!